# How to make prediction from regression model?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm working through a machine learning intro. Currently, I followed the class to build a regression model for salaries based on years of experience. By just looking at the regression model, I can eyeball how much someone with, say, 4 years of experience makes, but I'm wondering if there is a function or piece of code that can return the actual predicted salary.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

#Training Set
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Salary vs Experience (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Years of Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

#Test Results
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Salary vs Experience (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Years of Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

The code above is the model. Below is my code for making a prediction, but it doesn't work. Any idea how I can adapt the function to return a function based on the model?

```
def PredictSalary(experience):
    experience = np.arange(6).reshape((3,2))
    regressor.predict(experience)

PredictSalary(6)
```

My code above is trying to turn a 1d array into a 2d array, and then use the model to make a prediction on the salary for 6 years.

[image: regression plots]

Comment: `regressor.coef_` should give you the coefficients for each variable. Substitute your parameters in the equation produced by the coefficients.

Comment: Should regressor.coef_ replace (experience) in the function? Not sure how to implement your suggestion. New to coding!

Comment: Please provide the output of `regressor.coef_` and the columns used to train the model. I can provide better insight then.

Comment: regressor.coef_
Out[34]: array([9345.94244312])   The columns are as follows: X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values


#data splitting
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)

Comment: It seems that you only have trained on one variable and the weight of that particular variable 'Years of Experience' is 9345.94. If you want to predict the salary for four years of experience. The answer would be 4*9345.94 = 37393.76.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Given the regression plot examples in the original question, 37k is way off for 4 years of experience. I'll have to play around some more. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would suggest adding more features including 'Years of Experience' and running the regression model. That model would be a better one.

Comment: What is your x_train and y_train look like?

Comment: X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values


#data splitting
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)